# Insert in SQLite Database - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm currently working on my Android class project. I have some trouble with the insert statement in the database; I am using SQLite. When I'm running the application my database is correctly created but values are not inserted. I tried to refer my self to online proposals and solutions and i tried implementing it but with no avail.

Please I need some help.
Thanks.

DBHandler.java

```
package ck.edu.com.birch;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class DBHandler {

    String TAG = "Tennis Tracker";

    String DB_NAME = "TennisEFREI.db";
    String DB_TABLE = "statistics";
    int DB_VERSION = 1;

    String SQL_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE +
            " (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            "playerOnename TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "playerTwoname TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "winner TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            "wonPointsPlayer1 INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "wonPointsPlayer2 INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "wonSetsPlayer1 INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "wonSetsPlayer2 INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
            "acePlayer1 INTEGER, " +
            "acePlayer2 INTEGER, " +
            "winPlayer1 INTEGER, " +
            "winPlayer2 INTEGER, " +
            "errorPlayer1 INTEGER, " +
            "errorPlayer2 INTEGER, " +
            "date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
    String SQL_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE;

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBHandler(Context context) {
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);

        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_DROP);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        databaseHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertStatistics(String playerOnename, String playerTwoname, String winner, int wonPointsPlayer1, int wonPointsPlayer2, int wonSetsPlayer1, int wonSetsPlayer2, int acePlayer1, int acePlayer2, int winPlayer1, int winPlayer2, int errorPlayer1, int errorPlayer2) {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        String date = simpleDateFormat.format(new Date());
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("playerOnename", playerOnename);
        contentValues.put("playerTwoname", playerTwoname);
        contentValues.put("winner", winner);
        contentValues.put("wonPointsPlayer1", wonPointsPlayer1);
        contentValues.put("wonPointsPlayer2", wonPointsPlayer2);
        contentValues.put("wonSetsPlayer1", wonSetsPlayer1);
        contentValues.put("wonSetsPlayer2", wonPointsPlayer2);
        contentValues.put("acePlayer1", acePlayer1);
        contentValues.put("acePlayer2", acePlayer2);
        contentValues.put("winPlayer1", winPlayer1);
        contentValues.put("winPlayer2", winPlayer2);
        contentValues.put("errorPlayer1", errorPlayer1);
        contentValues.put("errorPlayer2", errorPlayer2);
        contentValues.put("date", date);
        Log.d(TAG, "VALUES : " + contentValues);
        return db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you know the insert does not work? If you're pulling the database file to see what's there, remember to either also pull the temp files (wal, shm), or just close your database to have the changes persisted to the db file. Other than that, use `insertOrThrow()` for helpful exceptions if the insert itself fails.

Comment: I went into the Device File Explorer saved the db file and the tried to view the content using DB Browser but nothing was inside. I also inserted data several times but the file size also never changed.

Comment: Did you check the return value of insertStatistics()?

Comment: Yes. When calling that method here is what i'm doing, just to be sure i'm doing it right:

`

        long savingStatus = dbHandler.insertStatistics(...myParams);
        if (savingStatus < 0)
            messageToast("Error Saving Statistics");
        else
            messageToast("Statistics Saved Successfully");

        dbHandler.close();

`

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#storageclasses) says:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:
>
> - **TEXT** as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
> - **REAL** as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
> - **INTEGER** as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.

So either convert your date in this format and try to insert or set your table's date column data type to text (which i won't recommend).